# Does Community user delete unanswered questions here?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at Meta Stack Exchange [at this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) and wondered if this is in effect here as well.
Questions with no answers or downvoted will be deleted after a month or year depending...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. That is network wide behavior.

The thought is that if no one has answered in that long of a time no one can or will. With the underlying assumption that if the question hasn't been edited or gotten votes its not all that useful to the community.